# Swift Sqlite inserting null in blob column

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have used the following query to create table in sqlite db

```
let createTableQuery = """
CREATE TABLE Image(
Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  image BLOB);
"""
```

Used the following method to insert data in Image table

```
let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO Image (image) VALUES (?);"

func insert() {
        var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            let image = UIImage.init(named: "item1.png")
            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData
            sqlite3_bind_blob(insertStatement, 2, data.bytes, Int32(data.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    }
```

When i call this method it print "Successfully inserted row". But when i open the db using DB Browser for Sqlite the image column has NULL value.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Your SQL has only one parameter. Why are you passing `2` to the second argument of `sqlite3_bind_blob` ?

Comment: You have a few issues.  The following line doesn't make sense.  sqlite3_bind_blob(insertStatement, 2, data.bytes, Int32(data.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

Comment: @ElTomato, what should be the correct line to insert blob data

Comment: @OOPer thanks your suggestion worked, i mistakenly passing 2, after passing 1, it worked.